# How to recognize set updated by .add() without using object.assign()

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I have some sets that receive additional elements through a socket without user input, but adding those elements with `.add()` in a mutator doesn't trigger an update in Vuex/Vue components.

I know using `object.assign({}, actualSetVar)` will force the application to react but I'm wondering if there's a cleaner or better way to do this without reassigning the entire object every time there's an update.

Answer (score 0):

Have tried using `Vue.$set`? It should allow you to get reactivity without using Object.assign. It will also allow you to set specific properties of an object vs. resetting the entire object itself. Outside of that, I don't think there is a "cleaner" way.

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-set